# Merge [ner] and [named-entity-recognition]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

These are the same thing, it's even made clear in the tag wikis.

From [named-entity-recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/named-entity-recognition):

> Named-entity recognition (NER) (also known as entity identification and entity extraction)...

From [ner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ner):

> The tag should be used for all natural language processing (nlp) questions involving named entity recognition, often written ner...

[ner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ner) is the less-used tag.

Comment: You can vote on this here. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/named-entity-recognition/synonyms